# Power BI Multiple Selections

Tags: powerbi

I am new to Power BI Desktop. I have integrated one data table into a dashboard and then created a dropdown list containing firm names from the table. I am wanting to be able to select multiple firm names at the same time which then populates separate summary tables for the firms that I had selected. Is that possible and how best could I do that? At the moment when I select 5 firm names all of the 5 summary tables show the same stats.

Many Thanks

Chris

Comment: Currently the question is vague and too broad for this format. Perhaps you could do a sketch of what you want to achieve, for example few simple schematic images for different scenarios.

Comment: If you're talking about dynamic number of table objects and dynamic positioning, PowerBI is not suitable for that. Otherwise, you need to give more information and what you tried so far. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you can fix that will be always 5 firms, maybe you could use 5 slicers and 5 tables. Then associate each slicer for each table. To do that, select a slicer and go to "format" and use the option "edit interactions".

Comment: @heringer I don't think interactions can hide tables?

Comment: @user5226582 I agree. That's why i stated "if you can fix that will be always 5 firms". So the user would use each slicer for each table. If one of the slicers is not used, the corresponding table will not be filtered but will still be visible. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes that's great. Thanks for your help